# Noise reduction hood @ exhaust vent

Tags: exhaust-vent, noise-reduction

I live on a busy street in San Francisco and recently installed an exterior exhaust vent line for my range hood (it used to be a worthless recirculating type). Doing so has increased the street noise coming into my place a good amount, and the noise is coming through the exhaust vent.

I would like to build a cover for the vent similar in design to the link at the bottom. While i know it won't eliminate the problem, i believe it will prevent enough noise from entering the vent to make a difference.

I am wondering if anyone here has done the same and/or what materials y'all would recommend using.

thx

http://www.enoisecontrol.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Enclosure-Material.png

Comment: That looks like it would make a fantastic nesting space for some birds, bats, and spiders.

Answer (score 1):

Add a range hood damper if you dont have one already, it should close off the tube when there is no airflow.

I would still build that enclosure though. The enclosure should be made of non porous, heat/flame resistant, and corrosion resistant materials since your exhaust would likely contain lots of water and oil vapors. Some suitable materials being galvanized steel, aluminum, stainless steel, and copper.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question and probably has been fixed by now, but you could add sound baffles. We use them in offices to eliminate sound from heating units.